# Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am using `Selenium WebDriver`  2.53.1 for `Visual Studio` 2015. I have a webelement I have called probably close to 1000 times and now I am getting a `no element exception`.

I have troubeshooted this issue using the following:

1. Checked given xpath error in stack trace and matched it against the html in firebug
2. Hovered over html and confirmed the same html highlights the button in the UI
3. Added a wait (Using `C#`)                     `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(btnNewCustomer));`
4. Selected elements around it to make sure there wasn't a bigger issue
5. I have defined the `WebElement` at the point in time its called
6. I have tried both

   `.Click()`
   `.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)`

I have exhausted all my options, am i Missing any other ideas?

Comment: So it turns out when I used ChromeDriver the button works fine. I'll continue to research into the IE issue. Thank you all

Comment: Try to reproduce this error on some public website and show us the snippet code

Answer (score 1):

Guess, but an educated one. I think, when you tried to add a wait, you actually issued `FindElement` before the wait which triggered `NoSuchElementException`. Try to do it this way:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var btnNewCustomer = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("id_of_your_element")));
btnNewCustomer.click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @alecxe but still receiving the nosuchelementexception with that code implemented.

Comment: @AndyWilliams but you cannot receive a nosuchelementexception with this code. You are probably looking for the element before the wait.